# Django admin exclude filter

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm looking for a way to implement exclude filter in django admin list view.

The case is the following:
In django admin I have a list of model instances, and I need to be able to show only instances that **does not belong** to some user for example (the **user is the FK** in the described model)

Is there any solution for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always make your own filter. [See an example here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)

Comment: But there is no SimpleListFilter in django 1.3, does 1.3 have this functionality?